# Numerical minimization of function

Tags: list-manipulation, algorithm, numerical-value

So I have the following equation:

```
3 Sqrt[9.15753*10^-6 + 25.1556 TolC^2 + 25.1556 TolL^2]==1;
```

Now TolC and TolL can take respectively the values of these lists:

```
CatalogC = {0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01, 0.005};
CatalogL = {0.2, 0.1, 0.05};
```

What is the best way to test what combinations of values verify the equation?

Comment: `Select[Flatten[Table[{TolC,TolL,3 Sqrt[9.15753*10^-6+25.1556 TolC^2+25.1556 TolL^2]},{TolC,CatalogC},{TolL,CatalogL}],1],#[[3]]==1&]` Probably the result will be `{}` telling you none are exactly equal to 1. If so then strip off the stuff outside the `Table` and see what all the results are.

Comment: Hey Bill! Thank you for your answer. What does that last 1 mean? Also is this valid for an inequation?

Comment: @Bill just identifying you so you see the messages

Comment: Ok Bill! Given that only the first solution interests me, how can I immediately select it?

Comment: You have two iterators in your `Table` so it will return a matrix. If you carefully read the docs for `Flatten` and think a bit then you might figure out that "last 1" will turn the matrix of results into a vector of results. That means the `Select` can pick items out of the vector for you. Try it on simpler made up examples to see how it works. Next, if you change `#[[3]]==1&` to `#[[3]]<1&` then it would select the results less than 1. Next you could wrap all the code inside `First[]` and it would discard everything but the first solution. Or there are other ways.

Comment: Yeah I am having trouble understanding that expression you gave me. I've tried to adapt it for outher function and got an error: Select[Flatten[
   Table[{TolR, TolC, TolL, 3 Sqrt[15.9457 TolC^2 + 15.9457 TolL^2 + 4.19142 TolR^2]}, {TolR, CatalogR}, {TolC, 
     CatalogC}, {TolL, CatalogL}], 1], #[[4]] < TolFreq &]

Comment: It worked by changing that 1 to 2. I have no idea what that means...

Comment: Look carefully at `Table[{x,y,x+y},{x,1,3},{y,1,3}]` and `Flatten[Table[{x,y,x+y},{x,1,3},{y,1,3}],1]` How are those different? Look carefully at `Table[{x,y,z,x+y+z},{x,1,3},{y,1,3},{z,1,3}]` and `Flatten[Table[{x,y,z,x+y+z},{x,1,3},{y,1,3},{z,1,3}],1]` and `Flatten[Table[{x,y,z,x+y+z},{x,1,3},{y,1,3},{z,1,3}],2]` How are those different? You want to see the values of the parameters and the value of the solution and you want a vector of those and you want to flatten the nested list just enough to accomplish that. If you remove the `,1` or the `,2` then `Flatten` will do too much.